# RegularExpression to split a string of information into separate blocks of usable data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Okay, I've been working solo on a project for a team of mine that tends to play on Minecraft a fair bit. As part of the project, I decided to add a system that saves and loads the players' inventory, armor, and enderchest, into a MySQL database using a plugin on the server. I've configured it to identify a Minecraft Account with the players within the server to display whether they're online on the server. I also have the plugin store the information in RAW data format.

I want this data to be editable on the website I'm building. Sort of like a premium feature that allows players to "pay" for new items and blocktypes using the currency defined by the website.

Everything was going A-Okay, until I realised that using my usual method to split the information into an array wasn't going to work. It turned out that I may need to use a RegularExpression formula to match each individual "cell" of information, and then split it using my usual method within the array.

The problem that I'm now facing, is that I don't really know a great deal about creating RegularExpression formulas. Especially not with a block of data this unusual. If any of you guys could give me a few pointers as to how one would do it, in simple terms, or even supply a RegEx that would do the trick, I'd be extremely grateful for your assistance.

Here's the RAW block of data:

```
{"type":"DIAMOND_SWORD","damage":2},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"ARROW"},{"type":"BOW","damage":4},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"}
```

I think you can tell that it's a pretty problematic block of data, so I'm pretty open to other solutions should you have them.

Comment: Looks like you can just wrap it with `[...]` and parse it as Json. See [`json_decode`](http://us2.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: That string looks very much like it is supposed to be JSON formatted. Don't use regex to parse that when PHP supplies the `json_decode()` function. (but note, as quoted, the string isn't quite valid json format, so `json_decode()` won't work, but it's very close; just wrap it in square brackets `[]`)

Comment: I actually stripped the "[]" to use a regex formula. The raw data does infact supply them.

Comment: @LeoV117 - that makes more sense now. I was wondering why you were being given broken json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is a JSON format , but not properly formed. You need to surround/enclose it with square brackets to make it a valid JSON.

This is the valid one.

```
$jsonData = '[{"type":"DIAMOND_SWORD","damage":2},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"ARROW"},{"type":"BOW","damage":4},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"},{"type":"AIR"}]';
```

Now with that you could make use of `json_decode()` to get them in an array.

Like this..

```
print_r(json_decode($jsonData,true));
```

See the working [<kbd>`demo`</kbd>](https://eval.in/96636) in action.

Comment: I'm surprised by both the response time, and the simplicity... Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you answer such questions, you'll get this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482698/php-method-json-decode-breaks-due-to-other-properties. Be careful what is worth to answer and what is worth to close and down-vote